# What does project location mean in SBT?

Tags: sbt, sbt-0.13

To define a project, I do

```
project in file(".")
```

What is the function of `file(".")`, as opposed to settings `baseDirectory`?

For example, what is the difference between

```
lazy val myProject = project in file("foo")
```

and

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).settings(
  baseDirectory := file("foo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For projects, there is no difference between using `project in file(...)` and setting `baseDirectory` yourself. use `show baseDirectory` to convince yourself :)

However, since `baseDirectory` is a setting, it can be used with any scope, e.g. you can set the base directory for a specific configuration or task.